# No Match for argument: php5-mysql and No package php5-mysqlnd available

Tags: php, mysql5.6

I came across the following warning :

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50550 Library:50631 in /var/www/html/web_app/test/browser/dbconn.php on line 31
```

After researching online, I came to know that I would need to remove the following version of MySQL driver `php-mysql` and install `php-mysqlnd` as [mentioned here for example](https://elgg.org/pages/view/2045983/tip-how-to-fix-the-problem-with-mysql-56) and [here as well](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/after-mysql-update-headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch.65439/). I did the following and got the following results:

**Removal Step :**

```
[root@myservername username]# sudo yum remove php5-mysql
Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin, ulninfo
This system is receiving updates from ULN.
No Match for argument: php5-mysql
No Packages marked for removal
```

**Installation step:**

```
[root@myservername username]#sudo yum install php5-mysqlnd
Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin, ulninfo
This system is receiving updates from ULN.
No package php5-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Here is my Linux Server related information for the reference:

```
[root@myservername username]# cat /etc/*-release
Oracle Linux Server release 7.2
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.2"
ID="ol"
VERSION_ID="7.2"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:2:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.2
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.2
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
Oracle Linux Server release 7.2
```

I believe because of above PHP warning, I am getting other mysql connection related errors. The reason I suspect PHP warning is the cause for the other errors is because the same code runs perfectly fine in my localhost with phpmyadmin.

My PHP Version is: 5.4.16

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

Also, if you list the contents of

```
sudo yum list installed | grep php
```

and the output of

```
ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/
```